# Почему возведение в степень работает не так как я думаю

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = 2, n = 3;
            int num;
            num = x;

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                num *= x;
            }


            Console.WriteLine(num);
        }
    }
}
```

Доброго времени суток, простите за глупый вопрос, подскажите почему результат возведения в степень 16 а не 8

Comment: вы имеете на старте 2^1, и после этого умножаете это на 2 три раза в цикле, получаете 2^4 или 16

Comment: Потому что отдебажьте код. Проставьте `n = 0`, какой должен быть ответ? И какой у Вас?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так исправить

```csharp
int x = 2, n = 3;
int num;
num = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   num *= x;
}
```

А можно так

```csharp
int x = 2, n = 3;
int num;
num = x;

for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
   num *= x;
}
```

Разберите оба варианта используя [отладку](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019).

Чем эти варианты отличаются? Какой из них лучше и почему?